# Excel formula to search for word in range and display corresponding ID

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have worksheet with data and would like to get ID's to cell B25, B26 and B27 if there are certain words in a range.

Range to search from: `B22:Z22`

Range to get ID: `B23:Z23`

**Example:**

Search for word `Generator` in range `B22:Z22` it is inside `IMA G4 (Generator, voimalaitos)`

Formula output:
Display corresponding ID to B25

[image]

Comment: What happens if "Generator" is in more than one column? Or is that not possible with your data?

Comment: `=HLOOKUP("*"&A25&"*",$22:$23,2,FALSE)`

Comment: @BruceWayne not possible in my setup

Comment: @ScottCraner this seems to work!

Comment: @ScottCraner you can add your comment as an answer